# How to find extra/different rows in table compared with another table?

Tags: sql, database, rows, except

I am trying to find the rows that are extra or different when comparing two tables in SQL Server.

For example, #temp1 has 5000 rows and #temp2 has 5125 rows.

I've tried doing

```
SELECT * FROM #temp1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM #temp2
```

but it returns empty results.

So I tried

```
SELECT * FROM #temp1
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM #temp2
```

and this returns 5000 rows, which is the amount of rows from #temp1, so that shows me that #temp2 contains all the rows that exist in #temp1, but it just has 125 extra rows. I am trying to write a query that shows just those extra 125 rows from #temp2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your order is not correct

```
SELECT * FROM #temp2
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM #temp1
```

Comment: I am using SQL Server, I don't think MINUS exists for SQL Server as I just tried it.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM #table2 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM #table1 
     WHERE #table1.PK = #table2.PK)
```

Or

```
SELECT *
FROM #table2 t1
LEFT JOIN #table2 t2 ON t2.PK = t1.PK
WHERE t2.PK IS NULL
```

This would work on any of SQL databases

Answer (score 1):

One fun way is:

```
(SELECT * FROM #temp2
 UNION 
 SELECT * FROM #temp2
) EXCEPT
(SELECT * FROM #temp1
 INTERSECT
 SELECT * FROM #temp2
)
```

This just shows the unique rows that are different.  It doesn't show which table they were originally in.